# Is there a quick way to notate 'any intersection of these sets is the empty set'?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a quick way to notate 'any intersection of these sets is the empty set'?

I have a number of sets, I want to express that none share any elements with any other. Is there a way to express that other than individually notating every intersection as equal to the empty set?

---

Edit:

From PJS36's answer, I found an answer to the question of notation on [wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjointSets.html):

> sets $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ are disjoint if $ A_i \cap A_j =\emptyset$ for $  i\neq j$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase I've always seen/used is "pairwise disjoint." Given sets $A_i$, if $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$, we say that the sets are *pairwise disjoint*.

Comment: That's helpful. Just read the article on Wikipedia. It's the exact notion that I want. However, the article didn't say how to notate, say, eight, "mutually disjoint" sets.

Comment: Oh, notation... Yeah, I would just throw in the phrase "pairwise disjoint", rather than coming up with some kind of notation scheme. I don't know if any notation for that situation exists.